# How to create new child instance from parent class using vector class object pointers?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a parent class `Product` and it has two child class `Wet` and `Dry` connected through inheritance. I also created a vector of `Product` objects pointers to store the new instance. I am trying to do an if statement, if user enter "wet" for its category then `Wet` instance will be created and also the same if "dry" entered then `Dry` instance will be created. How to achieve this ?

```
//PRODUCT
class Product
{
    protected:
        int quantity;
        double price;
        int code;
        string name;
        Manufacture manu; //other class obj
    public:
        Product(int q, double p, int c, string n, string mName, string mAdd, string mCon) : manu(mName, mAdd, mCon)


    void edit(vector<Product*>& _product){
                            string  Pname, Mname, Madd, Mcont;
                            float Pprice;
                            int Pquantity, size = _product.size(), Pcode;
                            char Pcategory;
                            
                                        cin.ignore();
                                        cout<<endl;
                                        cout<<"enter Product Code:" ;
                                        cin>>Pcode;
                                        cout<<"enter Product name:" ;
                                        getline(cin,Pname);
                                        cout<<"enter Product Price:" ;
                                        cin>>Pprice;
                                        cout<<"enter Product Quantity:" ;
                                        cin>>Pquantity;
                                        cout<<"enter Product Category Wet/Dry (w/d):" ;
                                        cin>>Pcategory;
                                        cout<<"enter Manufacturer Name:" ;
                                        cin>>Mname;
                                        cout<<"enter Manufacturer Address:" ;
                                        cin>>Madd;
                                        cout<<"enter Manufacturer Contact Number" ;
                                        cin>>Mcont;

                                                if(Pcategory == 'W' || Pcategory == 'w'){
                                                   _product.push_back(new Wet(Pquantity, Pprice ,Pcode, Pname, Mname, Madd, Mcont));
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                   _product.push_back(new Dry(Pquantity, Pprice ,Pcode, Pname, Mname, Madd, Mcont));
                                                }
                                                cout<<"successfully added new product!"<<endl;
    }
};

//WET PRODUCT
class Wet : public Product
{
    public:
        Wet(int pQuan, double pPrice, int pCode, string pName, string mName, string mAdd, string mCon) : Product(pQuan, pPrice, pCode, pName, mName, mAdd, mCon){}
};

//DRY PRODUCT
class Dry : public Product
{
    public:
        Dry(int pQuan, double pPrice, int pCode, string pName, string mName, string mAdd, string mCon) : Product(pQuan, pPrice, pCode, pName, mName, mAdd, mCon){}      
};
```

This is my attempt and I got the the following error :

```
if(Pcategory == 'W' || Pcategory == 'w'){
    _product.push_back(new Wet(Pquantity, Pprice ,Pcode, Pname, Mname, Madd, Mcont));
}
else{
    _product.push_back(new Dry(Pquantity, Pprice ,Pcode, Pname, Mname, Madd, Mcont));
}
cout<<"successfully added new product!"<<endl;
goto userInputAddLabel;
```

the error:
`expected type-specifier before 'Wet'`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the order of your code

```
_product.push_back(new Wet(Pquantity, Pprice ,Pcode, Pname, Mname, Madd, Mcont));

...

class Wet : public Product
{
    public:
        Wet(int pQuan, double pPrice, int pCode, string pName, string mName, string mAdd, string mCon) : Product(pQuan, pPrice, pCode, pName, mName, mAdd, mCon){}
};
```

You are using `Wet` (and `Dry`) before you have defined them. That's why the compiler doesn't recognise them.

To fix you will have to move the definition of `Product::edit` out of the `Product` class and place in somewhere in your code so that it occurs after the declarations of `Wet` and `Dry` have been seen by the compiler.